# Verification of linear combinations of a normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

A machined part consists of 5 independent components connected end-to-end. Two of these have lengths $N(37.0, 0.49)$, and three of these have lengths $N(24.0, 0.09)$. All measurements are in mm. What is the probability that the assembled part will be between 144 and 147 mm in length?

In answering this, I'm doing the following, but the answer is apparently not correct:

$$A = N(37.0, 0.49)$$
$$B = N(24.0, 0.09)$$
Linear combination...
$$Y = 2A + 3B$$
$$Y \sim N(2\cdot37.0 + 3\cdot24.0, 2^2\cdot0.49 + 3^2\cdot0.09)$$
$$Y \sim N(146.0, 2.77)$$

Therefore, the CDF between 144 and 147 should be:

$$\phi\left(\frac{147-146}{\sqrt{2.77}}\right)-\phi\left(\frac{144-146}{\sqrt{2.77}}\right) = 0.61128$$

The rational here is that the CDF at the specified points (144 and 147) gives $P(Y\le144)$ and $P(Y\le147)$, so we can subtract one from the other to get the cumulative probability between them. This makes intuitive and mathematical sense to me.

However, the answer given is 0.7777, and I'm not seeing how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have **five** independent random variables, $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,B_3$. The sum $Y$ of the lengths is given by $Y=A_1+A_2+B_1+B_2+B_3$.

The mean of the sum is the sum of the means, and the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances.

Comment: When that approach is used for this question the resulting variance of 1.25 still does not give 0.7777 as the result. Additionally, for any linear combination of normal distributions you have to square the coefficient for the distribution, no? For instance, when subtracting two distributions A-B, the difference gives the combination's mean, but the combination's variance increases since the -1 for "B" must be squared. Therefore, unless I'm mistaken, the variance of the combination cannot simply be the sum of them.

Comment: Scratch that...it does give the right answer (I forgot to take the square root of 1.25)...I'm not sure how one would determine how to distinguish between simply adding two distributions, or multiplying one of them by 2, and thereby getting a coefficient that needs to be squared...

Comment: The variance of a linear combination $\sum c_i X_i$ of independent random variables is $\sum c_i^2 \text{Var}(X_i)$. In our case all the $c_i$ are $1$.

Comment: In our case we have a sum of $5$ *independent* random variables, so what to use is clear. For $2A+3B$, the first two components would have to be identical twins,  and the others identical triplets, wildly not independent.

Comment: Ah! I see...yes that concept of independence has proven to be a bit challenging.